# Send text from textbox to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send input from a textbox to my PHP script, but it's not working.

When I change (in my PHP file)

```
$naam = $_POST["naam"];
```

to

```
$naam = "Marvin";
```

It's working!

AJAX/HTML

```
<td><lable>Naam</lable></td>
<td><input name="serarchName" class="tagert" type="text" id="searchName"/></td>   

    <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#searchName").change(function(){
                 var name = $("#searchName").val();
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'ontwikkelpunten.php',
            'method': 'post',
            'data': 
            {
                 naam: $("#searchName").val()
            },
            'dataType': 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);

                });
            });
        });
```

PHP

```
    $naam = $_POST["naam"];

$stmt = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM ontwikkelpunten WHERE naam = "$naam");
$stmt ->execute();
$myarr = array();
while($data = $stmt -> fetch()){
    $myarr[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($myarr);
```

Comment: `$conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM ontwikkelpunten WHERE naam = "$naam");` should be `$conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM ontwikkelpunten WHERE naam = '" . $naam . "'");`

Comment: You need to concatenate the variable `$naam` to the query as suggested by Nick Parsons..

Comment: @NickParsons No it shouldn't. What's the point in preparing a query when you don't bind any parameters anyway? Besides that, it looks like there are a couple of things wrong with his code.

Comment: Are you using PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: @icecub I'm just saying in terms of syntax their statement is wrong

Comment: @icecub i use PDO

Comment: Alright, try this: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ontwikkelpunten WHERE naam = :naam); $stmt->bindParam(':naam', $naam); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: @icecub I did try this, but my console log is still empty.

Comment: Yes, I think that's because you're encoding the data to JSON: `'dataType': 'json'`. Either remove that or decode the string in your PHP code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @icecub `dataType:` specifies the type of the response, not the type of the request.

Comment: Surprised no one pointed out you have a typo on trying to pass the variable in the first place. You have `naam: $("#searchName").val()` but the html input element is `input name="serarchName"`. Change the input name to `searchName` and it should go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not substituting the parameter into the query correctly.

```
$naam = $_POST["naam"];

$stmt = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM ontwikkelpunten WHERE naam = :naam");
$stmt->bindParam(":naam", $naam);
$stmt ->execute();
$myarr = array();
while($data = $stmt -> fetch()){
    $myarr[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($myarr);
```